# Update Listview via server and display the updated one without concatenated

Tags: java, android, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

Hello guys i have faced this problem for many days but do not find a correct solution on google. What i want to create a chat application that sync with my server i have implemented a technique that fetches data from server after every 8 sec and display in a listview the updated one and clear the previous one. Problem which i faced is that when i scroll my listview it crashes the application and display an error which i posted in logcat.

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 13, size is 0
```

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
Handler h;int delay;
private static final String REGISTER_URL =  "http://friends.ueuo.com/chat.php";
public static final String RECEVIE_URL = "http://friends.ueuo.com/rec.php";
String message,Sender_name;
public static final String KEY_SEND = "send";
public static final String KEY_RECEIVE = "receive";
public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "Message";

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,adapter1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Receive();

     h = new Handler();
    delay = 15000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            list.clear();
            Receive();
            h.postDelayed(this, delay);

        }
    }, delay);






    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_custom_layout,  list);

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
            message = edit.getText().toString();
            String sender = "Sender"+System.lineSeparator()+"";
            list.add(sender+edit.getText().toString());
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            registerUser();
        }
    };


    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);


}





private void registerUser()
{


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_SEND, "ad@gmail.com");
            params.put(KEY_RECEIVE, "bv@gmail.com");
            params.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}




private void Receive()
{


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(RECEVIE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {

            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void showJSON(String response)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    JSONArray users = null;
    try
    {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

        // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        //JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        // JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(2);
        // name = collegeData.getString("message");
        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++)
        {

            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            message=jo.getString("message");
            Sender_name=jo.getString("sendby");
            if (Sender_name.equals("ad@gmail.com"))

            {


                String sender="Wajid Usman"+System.lineSeparator()+"";
                list.add(sender+message);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }
            else

            {

                String receiver="Salman"+System.lineSeparator()+System.lineSeparator();
                list.add(receiver+message);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }



        }


    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I think this code isn't related to the error. But as said in the answer you are trying to get an element from an empty List

Answer (score 0):

It means you have ArrayList which having 0 elements where you can get each element like 0,1,2, ecc positions. And you are trying to read 12th element which does not exists into ArrayList.

Comment: Because the list is empty, as said in the logcat: index 13, `size is 0`